# Converting some legacy VB.NET code to C#, what is it doing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

**Reference:**

```
Public Const COLUMN_MODEL_ORDER As String = MDL_ORDER.ColumnName
```

`DataModel.Config.DefaultView` is a `System.Data.DataView`

**What is this doing and how can I convert it?:**

```
Dim ModelOrder As Integer = 1
Dim DataModel As New ProfileDataModel(New DBConnection, Me.ProfileID)
If DataModel.Config.DefaultView.Count > 0 Then
    'what is this line doing?'
    ModelOrder = CInt(DataModel.Config.DefaultView.Item(DataModel.Config.DefaultView.Count - 1)(Common.ProfileConfigs.COLUMN_MODEL_ORDER)) + 1
End If
```

Comment: Do you have a class or module called "Common" with a "ProfileConfigs" variable in it?  Do a search in the VB 6 project for COLUMN_MODEL_ORDER.  What it is doing is specifying a column in the current row based on a certain "model order."

Comment: Not sure if you were aware of this site already, but I use it when converting code as a quick solution: http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Operates on the last row in the dataview
2. Pulls the value from the field whose name is represented in MDL_ORDER.ColumnName
3. Converts it to an integer
4. Adds one to it.

Others have posted how to convert this specific code, however, in general if you have some vb.net that you are unsure of how to code in C# simply grab [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and you can decompile it and browse in either language.

Answer (score 1):

It takes the value of the last row's order column, converts it to an Integer, and adds 1 to it.

Comment: It contains the order column's ColumnName.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, its indexers:

```
if (DataModel.Config.DefaultView.Count > 0)
{
    ModelOrder = (int)DataModel.Config.DefaultView[DataModel.Config.DefaultView.Count - 1][Common.ProfileConfigs.COLUMN_MODEL_ORDER] + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's taking the value from last row in the DataView and the column defined by COLUMN_MODEL_ORDER and adding 1 to it.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like Item is also an array, so it's accessing by index the first array then accessing by index the value of the second array

```
ModelOrder = Convert.ToInt32(DataModel.Config.DefaultView.Item[DataModel.Config.DefaultView.Count - 1][Common.ProfileConfigs.COLUMN_MODEL_ORDER]) + 1
```

Comment: I think in C# you would do: DataModel.Config.DefaultView[DataModel.Config.DefaultView.Count - 1][Common.ProfileConfigs.COLUMN_MODEL_ORDER]

Comment: Item can only be used in VB and is actually a property with a parameter.